# How to set auto click function for html repeated input field buttons when value exit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to add autoclick functionality for my repeated input field butttons.

i tried following code but its not work.

```
 <table id="rf_id" >
                      <div class="form-group row col-sm-5" id="rf">
                                    <tbody id="rf123">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td> </td>
                                                    <td> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter product RFID code"
                                                            id="rfid_0" class="form-control" name="rfid[]" onclick="myFunction();" autofocus></td>

                                                    <td> <i class="fa fa-trash-o delete_rfid"
                                                            style="font-size:25px;color:red"
                                                            onclick="removeOptionRow('0');"></i>
                                                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle tr_rfid_add" id="tr_rfid_add"
                                                            style="font-size:25px;color:green" aria-hidden="true"
                                                            onclick="addFilterOptionRow();"></i>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </div>
                                    </table>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#tr_rfid_add').click(function(){
        var as = $('#demo').val();
    var cd = $('#rfid_' + as + '').val();
  alert(cd);  // showing input value
    });
  // set time out 5 sec
     setTimeout(function(){
        $('#tr_rfid_add').trigger('click');
    }, 2000);
});
```

expected:
following picture show my input field,if i entering any one input to the field example iam entered 'a' tothe field in the plus button click automatically.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you exactely want, but if the request is to wait a specific time after an input and then clone your input and focus the new one, this should do the job:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','.add',function(){
    let prev    = $(this).prev("input"); //get input field
    let old_id  = $(prev).attr('id').split("_");  //get current id
    let new_id  = old_id[0]+"_"+$('input').length; //set new id
    
    $(prev).clone().val("").attr('id', new_id).appendTo('.inputs').focus(); //clone input
    $('<button class="add">+</button>').appendTo('.inputs'); //add button
  });
  
  
  $(document).on('input','input',function(e){
    delay(1000).then(() => $(this).next('button').trigger('click'));
  });
});

//delay function
function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="inputs">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter product RFID code" id="rfid_0" class="form-control" 
    name="rfid[]"><button class="add">+</button>
    
</div>
```